# Understanding how Geoserver Plugin Zips are created

Tags: geoserver

I am working on fixing some vulnerability issues in some of the Geoserver plugins but cant seem to understand where some of the things included in the zip files on source forge are coming from. I have been looking at the pom.xml and the dependency tree but not able to figure it out. Can someone explain how these zips are created.

I have tried to look at the pom.xml and recreate by doing mvn install.